# C++ Include Statements and Linking

Tags: c++

I have always been told to never include a `*.cpp` file directly.

Is it good programming practice to only `#include *.h` files not `*.cpp` files?

Comment: "Yes", but that's a bit short for an answer :) (Though there were some hacks to achieve whole programm optimisation before it was commonly supported)

Comment: Understand what you're doing, why, and how. Then draw your own conclusions on what the best way to solve a problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could consider that good programming practice!

Having said that, there are no dogma's in programming.
I've come across some cases where it was very effective to include something else then a .h file.

But only do that if your have quite some experience and a very good reason to deviate.

As for the reason of using header files:

C++ is the successor to C. Traditionally C and C++ have no real module mechanism like e.g. Modula or Ada. In principle multiple C++ source files are compiled independently, only the linker sees them all once they're compiled. By putting e.g. class declarations in a header, the header becomes a kind of module interface. By including the header both in the .cpp file of module M where the class members are defined and in other modules that use that module M, a linking pin is created. The compiler can thus check if the declarations in M match the use in other modules. This enables cross module type checking.

Answer (score 0):

I also add that the most important fact is this that in c++ we have to distinguish between the definitions and declaration. If compiler encount two the same definition (function or variable definition) then throw error and end compilation. If we wants to use the same function in many translation unit which are compiled independently then you need declaration of this function. Thus we put declaration in a .hpp and this files can be #include by other files. In .cpp are placed definition (this means that compiler assign memory ). Let's think about global or static variable which can't be placed in .hpp files, because if compiler encounter two the same definition in the same namespace then quit compilation.